# Task :runners:google-cloud-dataflow-java:validatesRunnerLegacyWorkerTest FAILED

Tags: java, apache-beam

I am new to Apache beam, I have been following https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable to run tests over Cloud Data flow.

When I execute ./gradlew :runners:google-cloud-dataflow-java:validatesRunnerLegacyWorkerTest --tests "org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDoTest$OnWindowExpirationTests" --scan

I have been getting

```
org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDoTest$OnWindowExpirationTests > testOnWindowExpirationSimpleBounded FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException at ParDoTest.java:5544
        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at ParDoTest.java:5544
            Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException at ParDoTest.java:5544
```

**Task :runners:google-cloud-dataflow-java:validatesRunnerLegacyWorkerTest FAILED**

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace? Do you see this failure consistently?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i did not set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS values. After setting the value properly, i worked for me.

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/vend/Downloads/credentials.json"